# UIScrollView Center the View in Long Width

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView in my ViewController that has 1600Width and 600Height. i Put 3 images there so the swiping from left to right is nice until the each end. My problem is in the 2nd photo in the middle. i can;t make the scrolling stop on exactly on it.. how can i make the UIVScrollView centered?
I used this code to scroll from out of bounds

```
 [self.myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
 [self.myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1600, 600)];
```

Please help me through this. your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Paging might be what you need. See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html)

Comment: set paging property of scrollview to yes then set page width to the scrollview width or imageview width

Comment: can you provide a sample code? sorry im really new on this.

Comment: I provide some sample code for u, hope this will help for u.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)creatScrollViewWithimage
{
    UIScrollView *mainScrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    mainScrollview.pagingEnabled=YES;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        CGRect newFrame=mainScrollview.frame;
        newFrame.origin.x=mainScrollview.frame.size.width*i;
        UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:newFrame];
        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"]];
        [view addSubview:imageView];

        [mainScrollview addSubview:view];
    }
    [mainScrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(3*mainScrollview.frame.size.width, mainScrollview.frame.size.height)];

    [self.view addSubview:mainScrollview];

}
```

this will create scroll view for entire screen and add three `UIImageView` with paging enabled.